# Get Latitude and Longitude of the center in google map when dragged

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get alert the lat and long of the center point when I move my google map to any direction. How can I do this. actually my below code is not working in move condition.

```
   //Javascript For Google Map
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
    var center = map.getCenter();
    var lat = center.latitude;
    var long = center.longitude;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'dragend', getMinMaxLatLong(center));
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function getMinMaxLatLong(lat,long) {
    alert(lat+'==='+long);return false;
    $.get('getLatLong.php?lat='+latitue+'&long='+longitude+'&radius=20&unit=mi&type=cities',function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

The center lat long should be changed when I move or drag the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use [idle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) event instead dragend

> This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or
>   zooming.

Comment: I want to get the latitude and longitude of the center after moving the map

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are using `dragend` event which is fired only when the dragging stops. 
I think you should use the `drag` event like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'drag', getMinMaxLatLong(center));
```